# Internal server error on POST to /subscriptions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create a subscription to changes on the Inbox email folder.

The POST content is:

```
{
  "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
  "notificationUrl":"https://private_webhook_url",
  "resource":"/me/mailFolders('inbox')/messages",
  "expirationDateTime":"2018-12-22T12:08:59Z",
  "clientState":"a_client_state"
}
```

The result I get is a 500 Server Error with the following response body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: InternalServerError; Reason: Internal Server Error]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "5f581bcb-db5c-4842-b408-ee58d614cf98",
      "date": "2018-12-19T13:39:01"
    }
  }
}
```

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a problem with the Graph API. Is anyone able to help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Meanwhile I changed the "resource" parameter to "me/mailFolders('inbox')/messages" as per the examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0

The error persists.

Comment: What scopes have you requested in your token? Are you able to access the authenticated user's mailbox via Outlook (i.e. are you sure they have a mailbox provisioned)?

Comment: @marc-lafleur indeed the authentication/authorization worked. It was an issue with the clientState token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your clientState have CRLF characters because that is the error we see on the server side? Can you please try with a different value of clientState and confirm if it is working?

Comment: Thanks @meetali-goel, that was indeed the problem.